In Visual Studio Code can you change the menu font size?
In the file explorer when you right click a file a menu pops up, can you change the font size or compact-ness of this menu?
This menu used to either have less items or be more compact, but recently it has become more difficult to find what I'm looking for.
Example of the menu:



That happened to me before in Chromium
Press Ctrl + - if you want to compact it.
Or Ctrl + + if you wish to increase the size.

I appreciate the response but that's not the solution. That will make the entire screen smaller, I only want to make the menu smaller.
